# how to list all the files that will be affected by `git add .`?

Tags: git

Is there a method that I list all files affected by `git add.`?

Does the following command solve the problem?

```
$ git ls-files -c -d -m -o
```

Thank you

== Update ==

I have tried the `git diff --stat` and found that they are different from what `git add .` does.

Here is an example:

```
$ git status -s
D  secondB.txt
 M shareLineFile.txt
?? fileA.txt

$ git diff --stat
 shareLineFile.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

$ git add . --dry-run
add 'shareLineFile.txt'
add 'fileA.txt'
```

Comment: `git commit?` without editing ofcourse...

Comment: What do you mean by 'affected by `git add`' ?

Comment: @Rozart, I want to know which files will be added to the Index or which files will be deleted from Index.

Comment: And why is simple `git status` not enough? ;)

Comment: @Rozart I often wonder myself why modified files do or do not get into the index or those I have to add in using an explicit add.

Comment: `git add --verbose --dry-run .` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git diff --stat` is a fine answer, and will tell you the additions and deletions to files and such.

However, to answer your original question "list the files affected by `git add .`", you can just add the `--dry-run` option to see exactly what `git add .` would do:

```
% git add -n .
add 'foo/bar.py'
add 'README.md'
etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git diff --stat
```

This command will print summary of the files which will be added + number of lines when `git add .` will be executed.

[image]

---

Here is the git status for the above diff

[image]